# Not able to register instance programmatically with sproing-boot-admin

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Register instance programmatically with spring-boot-admin

I embedded spring-boot-admin into my application and it works fine but I cannot register an instance programmatically.

```
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private InstanceRegistry instanceRegistry;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Registration registration = Registration.builder()
                .name("test")
                .serviceUrl("http://localhost:4092")
                .healthUrl("http://localhost/actuator/health")
                .managementUrl("localhost:4092/actuator")
                .build();

        instanceRegistry.register(registration);
    }
}
```

no errors, but I dont see the instance in the web console and if I follow the code with the debugger it is not registered.

Comment: Same as https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/2514, waiting for feedback.